# BigQuery API: 400 Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ")"

Tags: pandas, api, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run query through bq python api(in standart sql mode), but have an error:

400 Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ")" at [1:621]

This is my code:

```
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    import pandas as pd
    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(r'/Users/dmitrij/Desktop/api-*****.json')
    QUERY2=("select date,pagePath,prev_page_path,hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,hits.eventInfo.eventAction,hits.eventInfo.eventLabel, COUNT(CONCAT(prev_page_path,pagePath,hits.eventInfo.eventAction,hits.eventInfo.eventLabel)) as count from (SELECT hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath, LAG(hits.page.pagePath) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS prev_page_path, date, hits.eventInfo.eventCategory, hits.eventInfo.eventAction, hits.eventInfo.eventLabel FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([api-open-broker.150225190.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -8, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))")
    query_job2 = client.query(QUERY2)
    df_prevp = query_job2.to_dataframe()
```

QUERY2 is in Legacy SQL Syntaxes, but if put code before like:

```
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_legacy_sql = True
```

I have an error:

400 Encountered "" at line 1, column 621.
Was expecting:
    ")" ...

This is QUERY2:

```
select date,pagePath,prev_page_path,hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,hits.eventInfo.eventAction,hits.eventInfo.eventLabel, COUNT(CONCAT(prev_page_path,pagePath,hits.eventInfo.eventAction,hits.eventInfo.eventLabel)) as count
from
(SELECT
 hits.page.pagePath AS pagePath,
 LAG(hits.page.pagePath) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime ORDER BY hits.hitNumber) AS prev_page_path,
 date,
 hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
 hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
 hits.eventInfo.eventLabel
   FROM
 (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([api-open-broker.150225190.ga_sessions_],
 DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -8, 'DAY'),         DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
   WHERE
 hits.type="EVENT"
 AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory LIKE "%Title_Name_Podpisat%" )
where prev_page_path is not null 
group by pagePath,prev_page_path,date,hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,hits.eventInfo.eventAction,hits.eventInfo.eventLabel
```

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

This error

> 400 Encountered "" at line 1, column 621. Was expecting: ")" ...

Means you didn't set your job_config and BQ attempts to run your query as standard sql, I would expect to see something like this:

```
query_job2 = client.query(QUERY2, job_config=job_config)
```

Another option is to use `#LegacySql` at the beginning of your code

Comment: job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_legacy_sql = True
QUERY2=.......
query_job2 = client.query(QUERY2, job_config=job_config)
df_prevp = query_job2.to_dataframe()

Comment: in this case i have en error: 400 Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 621.
Was expecting:
    ")" ...

Comment: And if you add this before your query instead #legacySQL (I tested this with a public dataset in the UI and it's working)

Comment: my code is like in the first comment( there before query) and i still have that error: 
 400 Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 621. Was expecting: ")"

Comment: My last suggestion go to the UI and check your Job history and check the details of the jobId. Good luck